# How do I to run Diaspora without SSL

Tags: diaspora

I want to run diaspora without ssl in my home based webserver in production mode. How can I do that? Are there any switches/options that I can turn off?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just set `require_ssl` to `false` in your `config/diaspora.yml`. Then restart Diaspora and make sure to clear your browsers cache, since redirects are cached by most browsers.

If you're using a reverse proxy also make sure you don't blindly follow the example configurations Diaspora provides, they do redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

However we strongly recommend to not do that, you can get a free certificate from startssl.com.

Comment: Yes I did it but when I run it in production, `http` is forwarded to `https`

Comment: In diaspora.yml, I set `require_ssl: false`, `certificate_authorities : ''` and `url : http...` even then it is not working.

Comment: Do not set certificate_authorities to an empty value, use one of the examples provided. This is not about a certificate you provide but about the certificate authorities you trust when making connections to other hosts that do have SSL enabled. It's very important, since over 90% of the network are on SSL you won't be able to send anything to them if that setting is set to an empty value or none existing file.

Comment: And again make sure to restart Diaspora and clear your browsers cache.

Comment: I tried setting the authorities to my `.crt` as well. It failed by pointing to `https`. I wish there was a simple option to set it on/off.

Comment: Do you use a reverse proxy? Did you turn of the redirect there?